# Colours and powers of Elfstones in Terry Brooks "The dark legacy of shannara"

Tags: magical-items, shannara

What are the colours and powers of the Elfstones?
I know the colour of two, but that is all.

1. Blue - gives ability to find.
2. Crimson - ???

Does anybody know the rest?

Answer (score 3):

This is the most I could find http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Elfstones

> There are five known types of colored Elfstones, though the explicit purpose of most remains a mystery. It should be noted that most can be used as a weapon against magical creatures, regardless of their primary function.
>
> - Blue Elfstones, also known as the Seeking Stones, allow the user to
>   find anything he or she desires, as long as they can form an accurate
>   mental picture of their query.
> - Crimson Elfstones act as a
>   high-powered, life-draining fiery weapon, capable of incinerating  an
>   enemy within moments. This comes at a cost of the user's life force.
> - Emerald Elfstones, function unknown.
> - Saffron Elfstones, function unknown.
> - White Elfstones, function unknown.

Comment: Additionally, the [Black Elfstone](http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Elfstone), which allowed the user to absorb magic into themselves, for better or worse.

Comment: Although this might not be canon, the [Shannara video game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannara_%28video_game%29) featured emerald elfstones. They were used for protection and healing, although they were broken by the end of the story IIRC.

Comment: Also in the series [The Genesis of Shannara] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Genesis_of_Shannara) the Loden Elfstone was used to contain and transport an entire city.

Comment: Whoops! I have only just now realized the title specifies a single series, "The Dark Legacy of Shannara". I thought it was asking about the Shannara universe in general. All of the elfstones I mentioned above appear in books outside of that series.

Comment: @Nathan I don't see why those you have mentioned shouldn't be included. I mentioned a specific series in the title, but that is only because I haven't read any others.